# Telerik RadOpen Command Reloads Parent Window and Scrolls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I am creating a modal popup window using the Telerik RadOpen function on an Asp.Net webpage.  The popup window appears correctly, but the parent window refreshes and scrolls the popup down the page.  How do I create the popup without scrolling the parent window.

The code I am using to create the popup is:

```
btnEdit.OnClientClick = _
     "radopen('newDialog.aspx?id=" + _id.ToString() + _
     "&_newid=" + _newId.ToString() + "', 'newDialog'); return false;"
```

I have already tried adding

```
<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

but this did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a handler to some of the RadWindow's event? For example the OnClientShow? It may be invoking an AJAX request or changing the scrolling position. Other than that your code should work properly (and it does on my end) as it prevents the postback from the button. You can also try adding the attribute to the HTML click event:

```
  btnEdit.Attributes.Add("onclick", _
 "radopen('newDialog.aspx?id=" + "id" + _
 "&_newid=" + "newId" + "', 'newDialog'); return false;")
```

Also confirm you have a RadWindowManager on the page as otherwise you would get a JavaScript error and there would be a postback. Then in the code-behind you could be creating a RadWindow that is actually shown.